# Json Escaping using JavaScriptSerializer Class?

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

Im using the `JavaScriptSerializer` Class to serilize and Deserilize in/to Json.

I `know` there is a `json.net` library out there.

But My question is :

Can I also use `JavaScriptSerializer`  class to escape my json string ?

or should I do it myself ? and if so should I do it by `encodeURIComponent` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it's an appropriate way to safely encode a string**. Just call serialize on your string.

To be more clear, if you look into the actual JavaScriptSerializer implementation (I'm using dotpeek), you can see that it actually calls this function:

```
private static void SerializeString(string input, StringBuilder sb)
{
  sb.Append('"');
  sb.Append(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(input));
  sb.Append('"');
}
```

So I guess another answer is that you can just use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`, although it won't add the double quotes around it.

Comment: Just what I needed! And there is an overload that takes an extra argument that will optionally add the outer double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on how you are using the json.

If you are sending out via an ajax call, then you probably don't need to do anything with the string.

If you are embedding the resulting json in a javascript variable from codebehind, then you only need minimal escaping to ensure the js is correctly formatted. This is what we use for this:

```
sJsonString = sJsonString.Replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n")
```

(Sorry, that is VB code, may need some adjustment for C#)

I think this may be the appropriate C# code:

```
sJsonString = sJsonString.Replace("\\r\\n", "\\\\r\\\\n");
```

Comment: However, don't forget to escape double quotes!